# bootstrap form-group control-label missplaced

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a form-group where the label is missplaced, the label is too far down compared to the dropdownlist, see image.

[image: Missplaced label]

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.deviceModel, "OS:", htmlAttributes: 
    new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.deviceModel, new SelectListItem[]{ 
      new SelectListItem{Value = "1", Text="iOS"},
      new SelectListItem{Value = "2", Text="Android"}}, 
      new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
 </div>
```

What have i done wrong, why is it missplaced?

Comment: By taking a quick look it seems that the select box is, when compared to the other elements, not styled by bootstrap. Maybe that causes the shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not into C# and Razor but based on my comment and looking at the code the `new`in front of the htmlAttributes for the Dropdownlist looks not right. It seems like the class is not applied to the Dropdownlist, which then could cause the shifting, probably caused by different margin parameters.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.deviceModel, "OS:", 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
  <div class="col-lg-4">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.deviceModel, new SelectListItem[]{ 
    new SelectListItem{Value = "1", Text="iOS"},
    new SelectListItem{Value = "2", Text="Android"}}, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" } )
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-2"></div>
```